# Exception Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

Tags: java

Tengo esta clase llamada `programa` :

```
public class Programa {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
    Persona p = new Persona("a","b","a","13-04-1994");
    String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/prueba";
    Conexion con = new Conexion(servidor,"root","");
    con.InsertarUsuario();
}    
}
```

y esta clase llamada `Conexion` :

```
package clases;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Conexion {
 private static String user;
 private static String psw;
 private static String servidor;
 private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 private static Connection con;

public Conexion(String servidor,String user,String psw){
    this.user = user;
    this.servidor = servidor;
    this.psw = psw;
    try{
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(servidor, user, psw);
        System.out.println("Conexión correcta");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("COnexión fallida");
    }

}

public void InsertarUsuario() throws SQLException{

    String sql = "Insert into prueba values(null,'borja','sanchez'";
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    st.executeQuery(sql);
    con.close();
    st.close();


}
}
```

pues al ejecutar el programa me sale la excepción:

> Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

¿como puedo solucionarlo?, muchas gracias

Comment: me pone cannot find symbol al ponerlo, se hace con el statement?

Comment: Voy a borrar mi comentario, ya que ExecuteNonQuery es para .net, y esta pregutna es sobre Java. En ese caso creo que buscas ExecuteUpdate

Comment: Lo primero que veo es que no cierras el paréntesis al hacer el insert

Comment: perfecto gracias me ha funcionado gbianchi

Comment: Me sucedió lo mismo, aquí tienes la solución https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905607/cannot-issue-data-manipulation-statements-with-executequery